# Django rest framework upload nested form data

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I have a front end react.js app that send a form data to a django rest framework end point. Basically, I want to create an order that consists of multiple ads, for now I am testing it using one ad. I am using a function that converts a `javascript` object to a `FormData` object from here https://gist.github.com/ghinda/8442a57f22099bdb2e34. As I understood from this function, the `FormData` object is just a text with a certain syntax, below are some object examples.

JavaScript object from browser console

```js
{user_id: 'google-oauth2|117955176430010920035', fullname: 'Full Name', email: 'gmail@gmail.com', phone: '', ordertotalprice: 1950, …}
ads: Array(1)
0: {display: 1, firstday: '2021-12-2', lastday: '2021-12-15', duration: 13, image: File, …}
length: 1
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
email: "gmail@gmail.com"
fullname: "Full Name"
ordertotalprice: 1950
phone: "0000000"
user_id: "google-oauth2|11795517643001"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

`FormData` Object from browser console using the `gist.github` link from above

```js
user_id google-oauth2|117955176430010920035
index.js:25 fullname Full Name
index.js:25 email mail@gmail.com
index.js:25 phone 00000000
index.js:25 ordertotalprice 1950
index.js:25 ads[0][display] 1
index.js:25 ads[0][firstday] 2021-12-2
index.js:25 ads[0][lastday] 2021-12-15
index.js:25 ads[0][duration] 13
index.js:25 ads[0][image] File {name: 'Picture1.png', lastModified: 1637958641422, lastModifiedDate: Fri Nov 26 2021 22:30:41 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 1094958, …}
index.js:25 ads[0][filetype] image/png
index.js:25 ads[0][originalname] Picture1.png
index.js:25 ads[0][price] 1950
index.js:25 ads[0][status] 0
index.js:25 ads[0][filehash] not available yet
index.js:25 ads[0][orderByNum] -1
index.js:25 ads[0][imgWidth] 1061
index.js:25 ads[0][imgHeight] 708
```

When sending this form data object to a `Django-rest-framework` api, it comes in this `QueryDict` format.

```py
<QueryDict: {'user_id': ['google-oauth2|11795517643001092'], 'fullname': ['Full Name'], 'email': ['mailg@gmail.com'], 'phone': ['0000000'], 'ordertotalprice': ['1950'], 'ads[0][display]': ['1'], 'ads[0][firstday]': ['2021-12-2'], 'ads[0][lastday]': ['2021-12-15'], 'ads[0][duration]': ['13'], 'ads[0][filetype]': ['image/png'], 'ads[0][originalname]': ['Picture1.png'], 'ads[0][price]': ['1950'], 'ads[0][status]': ['0'], 'ads[0][filehash]': ['not available yet'], 'ads[0][orderByNum]': ['-1'], 'ads[0][imgWidth]': ['1061'], 'ads[0][imgHeight]': ['708'], 'ads[0][image]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Picture1.png (image/png)>]}>
```

`Django models`

```py
class OrdersDj(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32, default=generate_uuid)
    user_id =  models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    # the rest of fields are in above objects

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["dateplaced"]

        

class AdsDj(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32, default=generate_uuid)
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrdersDj,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
    # the rest of fields are in above objects
```

The `order` object succeeds to be saved into the database but not the `ads`. Maybe the `FormatData` syntax is wrong but python cannot read the nested `QueryDict` objects. `ads[0][property]` maybe is wrong.